# MongoDB query performance - Memory footprint is high even with limited projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking at optimising my mongodb aggregation queries. One of the things I am observing in the query planner is that even though my index covers for the query the subsequent stage fetches the entire document in memory before projecting the actual keys.

e.g. I am querying on collection for last 6 months data

```
db.getCollection("formdatas").aggregate([

{
    $match : {
        "team_id" : "<team_id>",
        "template_id" : "<template_id>",
        "created_at" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2021-04-17T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2021-10-18T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }
},
{
            $project: {
                _id : 1
            }
        },

])
```

However when I look at the visual query explanation, it looks like below:

[image]

I am not sure why the entire 236MB odd data is pulled on memory even though I am just looking at `_id` in the projection.

Is there any way to further optimize this query to reduce the memory?

Answer (score 1):

That's the point, in most noSQL databases (and MongoDB here is no exception) you can't literally select a certain field, the engine of the database itself queries for the whole document.

As far as I know you could do nothin with that, except build a compound index for the selected field in the exact the same order: `"team_id": 1, "template_id": 1, "created_at": 1`

Comment: There is an index covering the match criteria, but does it need to fetch the document to project only `_id`

Comment: I see your point, if we return a key within out covered indexes then we can get away from fetching all documents. The blog here makes a good point explaining this https://betterprogramming.pub/improve-mongodb-performance-using-projection-c08c38334269